# How to extract substring from varible length column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi there I am trying to accomplish something similar to the mid function in excel with a column in a pandas dataframe in python.  I have a column with medication names + strengths, etc of variable length.  I just want to pull out the first "part" of the name and place the result into another column in the dataframe.

Example:

**Dataframe column**

```
MEDICATION_NAME
acetaminophen 325 mg
a-hydrocort 100 mg/2 ml
```

**Desired Result**

```
MEDICATION_NAME               GENERIC_NAME
acetaminophen 325 mg          acetaminophen     
a-hydrocort 100 mg/2 ml       a-hydrocort
```

What I have tried

```
df['GENERIC_NAME'] = df['MEDICATION_NAME'].str[:df['MEDICATION_NAME'].apply(lambda x: x.find(' '))]
```

Basically I want to apply the row specific result of

```
df['GENERIC_NAME'] = df['MEDICATION_NAME'].apply(lambda x: x.find(' '))
```

to the

```
 str[:]
```

function?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more examples? Is the name always followed by a space and numbers then mg? Are there some Generic names with spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DO with `str.split`

```
df['MEDICATION_NAME'].str.split(n=1).str[0]
Out[345]: 
0    acetaminophen
1      a-hydrocort
Name: MEDICATION_NAME, dtype: object
#df['GENERIC_NAME']=df['MEDICATION_NAME'].str.split(n=1).str[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`str.partition`** [`pandas-doc`]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.partition.html) here:

```
df['GENERIC_NAME'] = df['MEDICATION_NAME'].str.partition(' ')[0]
```

For the given column this gives:

```
>>> g.str.partition(' ')[0]
0    acetaminophen
1      a-hydrocort
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

`partition` itself creates from a series a dataframe with three columns: before, match, and after :

```
>>> df['MEDICATION_NAME'].str.partition(' ')
               0  1            2
0  acetaminophen          325 mg
1    a-hydrocort     100 mg/2 ml
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract` to use full regex features:

```
df["GENERIC_NAME"] = df["MEDICATION_NAME"].str.extract(r'([^\s]+)')
```

This capture the first word bounded by space. So will protect against instances where there are a space first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['GENERIC_NAME'] = df['MEDICATION_NAME'].str.split(" ")[0]
```