# Get first half of string from pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, string

I want to get the first half of a string from a pandas dataframe column, where the length varies row by row. I have searched around and found [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233104/how-to-extract-substring-from-varible-length-column-in-pandas-dataframe) but the solutions all focus on delimeters and regular expressions. I don't have a delimiter - I just want the first half of the string, however long it is.

I can get as far as specifying the string length I want:

```
import pandas as pd

eggs = pd.DataFrame({"id": [0, 1, 2, 3],
                     "text": ["eggs and spam", "green eggs and spam", "eggs and spam2", "green eggs"]})

eggs["half_length"] = eggs.text.str.len() // 2
```

and then I want to do *something* like `eggs["truncated_text"] = eggs["text"].str[:eggs.half_length]`. Or is defining this column the wrong way to go in the first place? Can anyone help?

Comment: what is your definition of first half,  is and included in the count? if you have three words how would you define half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a function to `text` column:

```py
import pandas as pd

eggs = pd.DataFrame({"id": [0, 1, 2, 3],
                     "text": ["eggs and spam", "green eggs and spam", "eggs and spam2", "green eggs"]})

eggs['truncated_text'] = eggs['text'].apply(lambda text: text[:len(text) // 2])
```

Output

```
|   id | text                | truncated_text   |
|-----:|:--------------------|:-----------------|
|    0 | eggs and spam       | eggs a           |
|    1 | green eggs and spam | green egg        |
|    2 | eggs and spam2      | eggs an          |
|    3 | green eggs          | green            |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using vectorized operations, which is faster than the .apply method. I read this interesting article which explains vectorized operations more in-depth https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/

An example of using vectorized operations for strings can be found in the following post: [Pandas make new column from string slice of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789445/pandas-make-new-column-from-string-slice-of-another-column)